# Sys.path.insert inserts path to module but imports are not working

Tags: python, django, path, sys, sys.path

I want to import a module in a project and it gives me lots of troubles because of an import error. So I decided to write a little test to see where the problem lies. I add a folder to my sys path and try to import it. And I get an `Import Error: no module found named xyz`

Like this:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../myfolder'))
import myfolder
print(sys.path)
```

The sys.path is `['/Users/myuser/myproject/mywebsitefolder/myfolder/', ...]`

`myfolder` contains an `__init__.py` file. Hardcoding the path to myfolder has same results. Other questions on the web solve the problem by either adding the correct path or by adding an init. But I have both I think and the problem remains.

I was under the impression that python looks in the system path for importable modules or do I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

If I understand correctly, is there any way I can debug this further? Or could this be a problem with python versions?

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my structure of my directories

- mywebsitefolder

  - myfolder

    - api_supply

      - tests (contains all my tests with many files)
      - **init**.py
      - serializers.py
      - urls.py
      - views.py
    - api_demand

      - tests (contains all my tests with many files)
      - **init**.py
      - serializers.py
      - urls.py
      - views.py
    - migrations (folder)
    - templates (folder)
    - **init**.py
    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - models.py
    - tests.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py

Comment: If you're trying to import `myfolder`, it is the *parent* - ie `mywebsitefolder` - that you need to add to sys.path.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I also tried this. Doing ```sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/Users/myuser/myproject/mywebsitefolder/'))``` gives me the same error

Comment: Can you show the actual contents of mywebsitefolder and its subdirectories?

Comment: yes of course. Updated my question.

Comment: I can't see the structure from that - is myfolder inside mywebsitefolder? - and I can't see what you are trying to import. But, this is clearly a Django project; so why do you need to do this at all? Your project will already be on the path, you should be able to import anything within it already.

Comment: Yes my folder is inside mywebsitefolder. Actually you were right again... ```Doing sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/Users/myuser/myproject/mywebsitefolder/')``` does work. My mistake, I tried it in my shpinx project and not in my test script and the error changed. I was too quick checking. In my test script it does work. I get other import errors in my sphinx build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the code as this you dont need to add the folder to the path all you need is the path to the folder

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
import myfolder
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: thanks ArunJose_intel! I also tried this, but it gives me the same error unfortunately...

Comment: can you try sys.path.append('/Users/myuser/myproject/mywebsitefolder/')

Comment: In the directory structure posted your myfolder is in the same level as mywebsitefolder so it should be sys.path.append('/Users/myuser/myproject/')

Comment: Thanks ArunJose_intel ```'/Users/myuser/myproject/mywebsitefolder/``` actually worked. I mixed my test script up with my sphinx build where I was trying it. I get other import errors there but this one is solved. Thanks so much for the help